# Gnosis Service Transaction Creation

Tags: gnosis, gnosis-safe

As I understand there are multiple service transaction for each network. These are communicating with client-gateway via config service. Config service checks the status of service transaction for each network. How config transaction does this, I mean how it checks the status of each service transaction? And how each service transaction instance created per each network, where do we decide this?

Answer (score 2):

The services are a layer on top of the contracts that make it easier to use these and they power the official web interface. The web interface hosted by the Safe team use the services hosted by the Safe team. Therefore it the Safe team decided what networks to support via these services. To add a new network you should reach out to the Safe team on their discord (you can find the link to it on https://www.gnosis-safe.io, under the community menu).

The client gateway provides an optimized API for the official web interface and allows data aggregation of multiple sources and heavy caching to handle a large amount of requests. To invalidate these caches the transaction service triggers a webhook on the client gateway.

To understand how the services work together it helps to read https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/service-architecture and look into https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure. This will also help you in case you want to run your own Safe services setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard, I got it safe team decides to add new network and as I understand I could not add on my own. So where is these network hosts and configs kept in the code, how can I see hosted networks and their hosting address?

Comment: The easiest way currently is to use the client gateway: https://safe-client.gnosis.io/v1/chains

Comment: We will improve our documentation on this to provide an overview in our docs on the available networks.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers, if you provide more detailed documentation I will be grateful because your backend services are a bit complicated, and playing with them and seeing the effects from the client is a bit challenging task to do.

Comment: Here is a list of all the available services: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/backend/available-services

Comment: One last question, these hosted transaction service info and their hosting address are on the config database because config service need to check them. How config reaches them. And also you created transaction service per network right? In transaction service repo which file makes specific to one network in transaction service?

Comment: The configuration that make the service specific to a network is defined in the environment, so in our kubernetes config. You can see examples for the different env configurations in the transaction service. Each transaction service is registered by and admin in the config and this information is then used by the client gateway to serve the clients with data from the correct transaction service.

Comment: Is it possible to invalidate caches manually?